# How to combine two different random forest models into one in R?

Tags: machine-learning, r, random-forest

I have two different dataset with same variables. I have built training models separately using random forest. Now i want to combine both these models. Could anyone tell me how can i this be achieved? Do we have something called combine() function in R?

Regards,
Arun

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question has already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19170130/combining-random-forests-built-with-different-training-sets-in-r). It addresses the problem in hand.